# Gstreamer: rtsp stream and restream it

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer, rtsp

I need a GStreamer pipeline that can take a stream using rtspsrc and stream it to another RTSP server.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far...

Comment: Why do you want to do this in C++? It ought to be a trivial invocation of `gst-launch` with a two-part pipeline.

Comment: My problem is making a pipeline that can do streaming and re-streaming it.

I have run this pipeline but it has problem in re-streaming    
`gst-inspect-1.0.exe  rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.102:5554/playlist.m3u latency=100 ! videoconvert ! openh264enc background-detection=false ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 `